# Notifying dependent functions by using reactive values in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I understand that reactive values notifies any reactive functions that depend on that value as per the description [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/reactiveValues.html)

based on this I wanted to make use of this property and create a for loop that assigns different values to my reactive values object, and in turn I am expecting another reactive function to re-execute itself as the reactive values are changing  inside the for loop. Below is a simplified example of what i am trying to do:

This is the ui.R

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI 
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  titlePanel("" ,"For loop with reactive values"),
  # Application title
  headerPanel(h5(textOutput("Dummy Example"))),

  sidebarLayout(
  #Sidebar
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("URLtext", "Enter csv of urls", value = "", width = NULL, placeholder = "Input csv here"),
      br()

    ),

    # Main Panel
    mainPanel(

      h3(textOutput("caption")) 


    )
  )
))
```

This is the server file:

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  values = reactiveValues(a = character())
  reactive({
    url_df = read.table(input$URLtext)
    for (i in 1:5){
      values$a = as.character(url_df[i,1])
      Sys.sleep(1)
    }
  })
  output$caption <- renderText(values$a) 
})
```

This does not give the expected result. Actually when I checked the content of `values$a`
it was null. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using a `for` loop, try using `invalidateLater()` with a step counter. Here's a working example that runs for me with an [example csv](http://www.sample-videos.com/csv/Sample-Spreadsheet-100-rows.csv) found with a quick google search (first column is row index 1-100).

```
library(shiny)

# OP's ui code
ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  titlePanel("" ,"For loop with reactive values"),
  headerPanel(h5(textOutput("Dummy Example"))),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("URLtext", "Enter csv of urls", value = "", width = NULL, placeholder = "Input csv here"),
      br()
    ),
    mainPanel(
      h3(textOutput("caption")) 
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Index to count to count through rows 
  values = reactiveValues(idx = 0)

  # Create a reactive data_frame to read in data from URL
  url_df <- reactive({
    url_df <- read.csv(input$URLtext)
  })

  # Reset counter (and url_df above) if the URL changes
  observeEvent(input$URLtext, {values$idx = 0})

  # Render output
  output$caption <- renderText({
    # If we have an input$URLtext
    if (nchar(req(input$URLtext)) > 5) {
      # Issue invalidation command and step values$idx
      if (isolate(values$idx < nrow(url_df()))) {
        invalidateLater(0, session)
        isolate(values$idx <- values$idx + 1)
      }
    }
    # Sleep 0.5-s, so OP can see what this is doing
    Sys.sleep(0.5)
    # Return row values$idx of column 1 of url_df
    as.character(url_df()[values$idx, 1])
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Actually this did not help. it threw the following error: ERROR: [on_request_read] connection reset by peer

I am posting the two ui.R and server.R files after being simplified

Comment: I've updated the answer using the additional code that you provided. Let me know if this is better.

Comment: Can you please further elaborate on this chunk of code: 
`invalidateLater(0, session)
        isolate(values$idx <- values$idx + 1)`

Comment: I wrote some examples, perhaps it helps: http://qmviews.blogspot.ch/2016/12/r-shiny-some-reactivity-by-example.html

Comment: `invalidateLater()` will cause the reactive expression to re-execute after completion. `values$idx` lets us track which row we are displaying. Wrapping the `values$idx <- values$idx + 1` statement in `isolate()` will not cause `output$caption` to be re-executed immediately when it sees a change in `values$idx` and will instead display the row in the ui before `invalidateLater()` executes the expressions again.

Comment: While TMOTTM's examples show the power of Shiny's reactive classes, they aren't applicable to owise's question of displaying updates to the output object iteratively.

Comment: @Ben Fasoli: thank for this. So if I want to pause using an action button, should I work on the counter or on invalidateLater()?

Comment: You could use `observeEvent()` to watch for the action button and have the button change a reactiveValue.  Then, use this reactiveValue to add a condition to the `if` statement that triggers `invalidateLater`.